# Webstorm ignores ESLint indentation for JSX

Tags: reactjs, webstorm, eslint

When I execute "Reformat Code", my multi-line JSX components indent like this:

```
<SubTabBar clickHandler={subtab => this.setState({ subtab })}
           currentSubtab={subtab}
           sport={sport} />
```

They then have an ESLint error, such as "ESLint: Expected indentation of 10 spaces but found 19.(indent)"

When I right-click and do ESLint fix, I get this, which ESLint is happy with:

```
<SubTabBar clickHandler={subtab => this.setState({ subtab })}
  currentSubtab={subtab}
  sport={sport}/>
```

But this is untenable since "Reformat code" gives the wrong indentation, and especially because I have Reformat Code running on Commit! So it always winds up wrong!

I did do "Apply ESLint Code Style Rules" from .eslintrc but they don't help this case. I can't find anything applicable in the preferences (the oft-recommended unchecking of "Align when multiline" doesn't fix it.)

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

Whoops, figured it out! I thought it was worth mentioning here because it's very much not where I thought it was. These aren't simply JS settings. They're no section for JSX settings, but what are you doing in JSX? *Writing **HTML***.

In the HTML Code Style section, unchecking "align attributes" fixed my problem.

Comment: **Apply ESLint Code Style Rules** action mostly imports the core ESLint rules (`indent`, `semi`, `quotes`, etc). In particular, importing rules from `eslint-plugin-react` is not implemented (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-28857), so HTML formatter preferences are not changed when applying ESLint code style rules. You have to configure them manually in **Setting | Editor | Code Style | HTML**